# IComponent Load event

Tags: c#, winforms

The custom IComponent implementation is added to the main form via the designer mode and some properties are adjusted.

I need to execute something automatically after the properties of the component are set.

Something similar to `Form_Load(object form, EventArgs e)` is this possible?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Exactly what I needed, I did not know this interface, can you create one awnser, or should I ? So it does not disappear if there are changes in the msdn link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this answer based on the Hans Passant comment.

> **ISupportInitialize** allows controls to optimize multiple property assignments. As a result, you can initialize co-dependent properties or batch set multiple properties at design time.
>   Call the BeginInit method to signal the object that initialization is starting. Call the EndInit method to signal that initialization is complete. ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize(v=vs.110).aspx))

Basically I also need to implement the ISupportInitialize interface.

If I have this implemented, the designer will autmatically call this two methods before and after assigning the properties.

```
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.component1)).BeginInit();
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.component1)).EndInit();
```

That will allow me to execute something after the properties are Set, exactly what I needed.